# Java chat between mobile and web client

Tags: java, jsf-2, websocket, chat

I want to implement a chat between mobile client and person who works with web app. I investigated WebSockets and as I understand I can do it using just javascript and java. I'm using JSF with Primefaces for this app and I found a [chat implementation](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/push/chat.jsf) in Primefaces. But I am quite confused because it's an extension (even included separate framework Atmosphere). In source code for this example I didn't find any information about host. It is not an enterprise project (just self decision). I want to push my web client to some PASS Platform, send messages from mobile client, get it using web app in cloud and viсe versa.

I want to know Atmosphere is good for that or exists more simple ways to do it? I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What version of JSF are you running? In JSF2.2, there's native support for Websockets, with no add-ons.

Comment: @kolossus I just moved to 2.2

Answer (score 1):

The BridgeIt Echo Service and Push Service can be combined with AeroGear:

```
pipeline.add( {name:"items", 
    settings:{baseURL: "http://api.bridgeit.mobi/echo/list/", 
            endpoint:"aerochat"}
});
```

where you set up the push service as follows:

```
bridgeit.usePushService(
        'http://api.bridgeit.mobi/push/',
            apikey);
bridgeit.addPushListener('aerochat', 'app.refresh');
```

More details in the blog post: http://bridgeit.mobi/forum/index.php?p=/discussion/33/icepush-service-with-aerogear